# Layout issue in search icons & image upload dialog

Tags: bug, design

The search placeholder icon is misplaced when I open Stack Overflow in the Chrome browser. Also when I tried to upload an image, I couldn't see the **Add Picture** button. The dialog shows at the bottom of the screen and I can't scroll through.

**1: Search field problem**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**2: Image upload dialog**

[image]

[image]

Have anyone else faced this problem? Is it a bug?

Comment: No, works fine on my Google Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit) / Windows 10 (Resolution: 1920x1080)

Comment: Whenever you report layout bugs - include OS and Browser you have experienced this with (and their versions). Additionally - check the dev console for any errors and report them as well. Third step, just to rule out things - disable any extensions/plug-ins/add-ons and see if the problem is still there.